# Adicionar um novo objeto em uma lista em outra classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lista, arraylist

Populei uma lista de pratos de um restaurante, após isso, adicionei uma função para que o usuário crie um novo prato quando quiser. Porém, no método para criar o novo prato, não consigo adicionar na lista que está em outra classe. O código é esse:

Arquivo ProcessaListas.java:

```
List<Prato> listaPratos = new ArrayList<>(); // preciso adicionar o novo objeto nessa lista através do método

    while (leitorPratos.hasNext()) {
        linhaPratos = leitorPratos.nextLine();
        String[] partesPrato = linhaPratos.split(";");

        Prato prato = new Prato();
        prato.setPrato(partesPrato[0]);
        prato.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(partesPrato[1]));
        prato.setCodigo(codigoPrato);

        listaPratos.add(prato);

        codigoPrato++;

    }
```

E este é o método criado para adicionar o objeto na lista acima

Arquivo ProcessamentoPrincipal.java

```
public static void criarNovoObjeto(int choice) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeProduto;
    double preco;
    int codigo;
    codigo = 18;

    System.out.println("Escolha a opção que deseja adicionar: ");
    System.out.println("1. Pratos ");
    System.out.println("2. Bebidas ");
    System.out.println("3. Vinhos ");

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do seu prato: ");
        nomeProduto = sc.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite o preço do seu prato: ");
        preco = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        Prato prato = new Prato();
        prato.setPrato(nomeProduto);
        prato.setPreco(preco);
        prato.setCodigo(codigo);

        //listaPratos.add(prato); // esse .add não funciona pois não encontra a lista
        
        ProcessaListas.lerArquivoPrato(
                "C:\\Users\\igorm\\Documents\\FACULDADE\\2semestre\\Desenvolvimento de Software l\\Atividade4\\pratos.csv");
    }

}
```

como eu faria para encontrar a lista do arquivo ProcessaListas.java e adicionar o valor nela através do método criarNovoObjeto()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código que você apresentou do arquivo *ProcessaListas* parece estar incompleto. Todo arquivo java deve possuir ao menos uma classe.
Além disso, o código do laço while deve estar dentro de algum método ou construtor.

Para que você acesso a variável *listaPratos* a partir da classe *ProcessamentoPrincipal*, *listaPratos* deve ser um atributo da classe *ProcessaListas*.
Seu código está totalmente procedural, caso seu código seja orientado à objetos, você deveria criar um objeto de *ProcessaListas* para então conseguir acessar *listaPratos*.

O código de *ProcessaListas* ficaria como uma estrutura parecida com a seguinte:

```
public class ProcessaListas {

private List<Prato> listaPratos = new ArrayList<>(); 

public List<Prato> getListaPratos() {
    return listaPratos;
}

public void lerArquivoPrato() {
//aqui seria um método para ler os pratos de um arquivo
//mas o código que você apresentou está incompleto
}
}
```

E no método *criarNovoObjeto* ficaria algo assim:

```
public static void criarNovoObjeto(int choice) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeProduto;
    double preco;
    int codigo;
    codigo = 18;

    System.out.println("Escolha a opção que deseja adicionar: ");
    System.out.println("1. Pratos ");
    System.out.println("2. Bebidas ");
    System.out.println("3. Vinhos ");

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do seu prato: ");
        nomeProduto = sc.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite o preço do seu prato: ");
        preco = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        Prato prato = new Prato();
        prato.setPrato(nomeProduto);
        prato.setPreco(preco);
        prato.setCodigo(codigo);
        ProcessaListas processaListas = new ProcessaListas();
        processaListas.getListaPratos.add(prato); 
        processaListas.lerArquivoPrato(
                "C:\\Users\\igorm\\Documents\\FACULDADE\\2semestre\\Desenvolvimento de Software l\\Atividade4\\pratos.csv");
    }

}
```